# Variants of Nicholson's inequalities for prime numbers, involving the Lambert $W$ function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, inequalities, conjectures, prime-gaps

The purpose of this post is ask about two closely related/inspired conjectures from inequalities due to Nicholson (see [1]) and Visser [2]. If my reasonings are right should be stronger versions of Nicholson's inequalities that you can  see from the linked Wikipedia. My doubt is if there are some chances to disprove the following conjectures. The Wikipedia related to the Lambert $W$ function [*is this*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), I add it as reference to recall the definition and asymptotics. Here, we are denoting the $k$-th prime number as $p_k$, for integers $k\geq 1$.

**Conjecture 1.** *For all integer* $n\geq 5$ *the inequality*  $$\left(\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_{n}}\right)^n<n W(n)$$
*holds, where* $W(x)$ *is the main/principal branch of the Lambert* $W$ *function.*

**Conjecture 2.** *For all integer* $n\geq 1$ *the inequality* 
$$\left(\frac{\log p_{n+1}}{\log p_{n}}\right)^n<e^{-\gamma}\frac{e}{\Omega}$$
*holds, where* $\Omega=W(1)$ *is the omega constant,* thus here also $W(x)$ *is the main/principal branch of the Lambert* $W$ *function, and* $\gamma$ *is the Euler-Mascheroni constant* (as remark here, we add that $\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\Omega}=\frac{e^{\Omega}}{e^{\gamma}}<1$).

> **Question.** I would like to know if using the theory about prime numbers or prime gaps we can prove that some of previous conjectures (Conjecture 1 or Conjecture 2) is false/wrong. **Many thanks.**

I tried to write these in some way that these conjectures in the post harmonize well. I wrote some scripts in Pari/GP that can be evaluated in the web Sage Cell Server, feel free to ask about it in comments.

### References:

[1]  John W. Nicholson, see the section *Comments* for the sequence *A182514*
in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (2013), or the Wikipedia [*Firoozbakht's conjecture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture).

[2] Matt Visser, *Primes and the Lambert* $W$ *function*, Cornell University Library (November 2013).

Comment: I know that the article [2] is available also as the preprint on arXiv with identificator **1311.2324**

Comment: Many thanks for the upvote.